# Can I force a website to return Content-Disposition header?

Tags: http, web-applications, http-headers, urllib2, urllib

I see that some websites return Content-Disposition header, and some do not.

Is there a way for me to explicitly request the server to send back content-disposition?

Question is generic but I am using Python/urllib/urllib2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way to do that.